# Visual Studio breakpoints -- break on specific file access

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Is there any way of having a VS debug session break when a specific file is read from or written to?

In this case I'd want to use it as an exploratory tool -- assume I don't know where in a large codebase this file is being accessed from, or where the filename is being set -- it might be picked up from deep in some large scale config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is just quickly hack up a static class that uses the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to listen to file create/changed events, and put a breakpoint in the event callback, or put a call to [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) there.

Then, when it breaks, switch to the Threads window and try to locate the thread and the piece of code that did the actual file-access.

If you need to use this a lot, have this class maintain a list of specific file names you want to break on, and expose two public static methods: to Start and Stop listening to changes in a specific file.

Also, if you have VS2010 Ultimate you could simply search through the list of File Created events in the IntelliTrace events log.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it's quite possibly genius. I was thinking about FileSystemWatcher yesterday, wishing there were some way to hook it in. Nice idea, will give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in *any* access to the file, rather than just writes to it, `FileSystemWatcher` won't help.

A simple solution is to open the file in advance and wait for the other logic to access it, triggering an `IOException`. You can use the following helper class to break immediately - or VS's "First Chance Exception" feature:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

static class DebugHelper
{
    public static void BreakOnFileAccess(string path) 
    {
        var msg = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        msg = "The process cannot access the file '" + msg;
        msg = msg.ToUpper();

        var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        new Thread(() => {
            while (true) 
            {   
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                // ensure FileStream isn't GC'd as a local variable after its last usage
                GC.KeepAlive(fs);
            }
        }).Start();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.Exception is IOException && 
                e.Exception.Message.ToUpper().Contains(msg))
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for picking up so long after the question was asked. Why the GC.KeepAlive? Would having a static fs handle or list of handles have the same effect?

Comment: The KeepAlive call is to make sure the FileStream isn't GC'd, since local variables aren't guaranteed to stay alive after their last usage in the method. Yes, keeping a reference in a static field or collection would serve just as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently my process has to be:

- Find in files for the filename, or a partial filename
- Find in config files for the filename, or a partial filename
- Guess at object from filename or contents, find object in codebase, break on method entries
- (if xml, break on ReadXml to find out where opened ... )

which is clunky but does work ...

Answer (score 0):

You could set a conditional breakpoint.

Let's assume you have a string variable strFileName where the file name is stored.

On the line where the file is read, set a breakpoint. Right click on the breakpoint and click on "Condition...".

In the dialog do:

```
strFileName = "TheSpecificFileName.txt"
```

That would do the job if the file name is available that is being read.

Comment: Thanks -- but am assuming I don't know where in a large codebase this file is being accessed from, or where the filename is being set -- it mgiht be picked up from deep in some large scale config.

Answer (score 0):

A trick that worked for me was to change the access permissions for the specific file in Windows Explorer. Specifically, I set the *Read* permission for the file to *Deny* for my user profile. Then I ran my program and debugger stopped due to an `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Now I know the exact line that the file is accessed and I could place a breakpoint and restore the access permissions to how they were.

You may want to check *Exception Settings* within Visual Studio to make it will break when the exception is raised.